# effect of mvn -X option ? ie. corresponding property that can be detected inside poms?

Tags: java, maven

Please could anyone enlighten me if there is any property that Maven sets
when given the -X option that could be detected and passed to a script run
from an exec plugin goal - ie. something I could put into a Java System Property or environment variable that says "User has given the -X option on command line", so I could do something like:

```
 <environmentVariables>
   <ENABLE_DEBUG>${maven.some.property.set.when.debug.is_enabled}
   </ENABLE_DEBUG>
 </environmentVariables>
```

I've searched the web, documentation and source code to no avail.

Comment: Why not use profiles?

Comment: Yes, that is probably what I'll have to end up doing, but I was just checking if there was such a property - reading the source since posting shows there isn't one - it just sets : slf4jConfiguration.setRootLoggerLevel( Slf4jConfiguration.Level.DEBUG );

Answer (score 0):

Aha ! Found it : (in maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/logging/impl/Log4j2Configuration.java) :

```
public class Log4j2Configuration
    extends BaseSlf4jConfiguration
{
    @Override
    public void setRootLoggerLevel( Level level )
    {
    ...
       System.setProperty( "maven.logging.root.level", value );
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if this property was documented somewhere !